# Split dataframe into chunks and add them to a multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have an indexed dataframe which has 77000 rows.

I want to group every 7000 rows into a higher dimension multiindex, making 11 groups of higher dimension index.

I know that I can write a loop through all the indexes and make a tuple and assign it by `dataframe.MultiIndex.from_tuples` method.

**Is there an elegant way to do this simple thing?**

Comment: Can't you just do `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.tolist(), np.arange(11)], names=['first','second'])` to set the index?

Comment: If I do that, I will get a total number of 77000 from `df.index.tolist()`, and then times it by `np.arange(11)`, which will yield a number of 77000*11 index.  That is not dividing it but the opposite operation.

Comment: maybe you want to use [`np.array_split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) to divide the df into buckets

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the `pd.qcut` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) to create a new column that you can add to the index.

Here is an example that creates five groups/chunks:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':range(1,10)})
df['chunk'] = pd.qcut(df.data, 5, labels=range(1,6))
df.set_index('chunk', append=True, inplace=True)
df
             data
index chunk      
0     1         1
1     1         2
2     2         3
3     2         4
4     3         5
5     4         6
6     4         7
7     5         8
8     5         9
```

You would do `df['chunk'] = pd.qcut(df.index, 11)` to get your chunks assigned to your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The code below creates an ordered column in the range 0-10, which is tiled up to the length of your DataFrame.  Since you want to group based on your old index plus your new folds, you first need to reset the index before performing a `groupby`.

```
groups = 11
folds = range(groups) * (len(df) // groups + 1)
df['folds'] = folds[:len(df)]
gb = df.reset_index().groupby(['old_index', 'folds'])
```

Where `old_index` is obviously the name of your index.

If you prefer to have sequential groups (e.g. the first 7k rows, the next 7k rows, etc.), then you can do the following :

```
df['fold'] = [i // (len(df) // groups) for i in range(len(df))]
```

Note: The `//` operator is for floor division to truncate any remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the integer division `//` assuming that your dataframe has the default integer index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
# ===============================================
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10), columns=['col'])
df

# processing
# ===============================================
df['chunk'] = df.index // 5
df.set_index('chunk', append=True)

            col
  chunk        
0 0      2.0955
1 0     -1.2891
2 0     -0.3313
3 0      0.1508
4 0     -1.0215
5 1      0.6051
6 1     -0.3227
7 1     -0.6394
8 1     -0.7355
9 1      0.5949
```